# What would chemistry seniors like to hear about industrial hygiene?

Tags: safety, environmental-chemistry

I have a master degree in physical chemistry with close to 10 years experience as a chromatographer in pharma.  About two years ago I made a career change into industrial hygiene.

Right now I am prepping to give a senior seminar talk about my professional experiences as an industrial hygienist at the college where I earned my BS in chemistry.  The talk will be half lecture and half lab - I'll be bringing in some equipment to demonstrate.

What would chemistry students be particularly interested in hearing about from someone in industry?

Comment: Asking in Chemistry instead of Careers due to the specialized nature of the question.

Answer (score 2):

To keep this answer as far from opinionated as possible, I'd suggest some of the W's:

- **What** is industrial hygiene? (I've never heard of the term before this post and actually had to look it up myself.)
- **How** do you do industrial hygiene? Procedures, risk assessment...
- **Why** is industrial hygiene important? You might give examples where disaster was averted thanks to IH, and an example where it would have helped if done right.
- **Where** is industrial hygiene applied? (I guess the office building will have less rigorous guidelines than the production facility.)
- **When** did industrial hygiene start to be a thing? A small historical overview could be given, you could even give a **who** to this one if it was some distinct person who came up with the idea.

Always good is a personal anecdote, something you witnessed or someone (whom you trust as a source) told you, highlighting the bullet points above.